# Complexity of a recursive function with a loop

Tags: algorithm, recursion, ocaml, complexity-theory

I have a recursive function working on a list, the function contains a loop where itself is called, and ends up with another function `g`. Its structure is similar as follows, to simplify the issue, we can assume that `l` is always a list without duplicate elements.

```
let rec f l = function
  | [] -> g ()
  | _ ->
      List.fold_left
        (fun acc x ->
           let lr = List.filter (fun a -> (a <> x)) l in
           acc + (f lr))
        1 l
```

I am not sure how to express the complexity of this function, with `List.length l` and the complexity of `g`.

I think it is proportional to the complexity of `g` and the **factorial** of `List.length l`, could anyone confirm?

Comment: What language is this? Can you tag it with the language name? Can you describe what's going on at a high level? Why is it pattern-matching on `[]` to return a function, but otherwise returns a non-function? What is `rec f l` supposed to do? What do `f` and `l` mean?

Comment: can you edit the code/pseudocode and make it simple? it is pretty hard on my eyes. **edit** is this ocaml code? can you give a pseudocode or some kind of generic code? (never used ocaml)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it is `OCaml`...

Comment: (For what it's worth, the code you've given doesn't actually *call* `g`.  It just returns `g` as a value.  Since it also adds the return value of `f` to `acc`, you can conclude that `g` must be an int, not a function.  It would be better to post working code, I think.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield: indeed, `g` is a function, so i just added a `()`.

Comment: I don't see how this code type-checks. The recursive call to `f` is missing its second argument (whose presence also seems irrelevant to the question, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assume that the list `l` does not contain any duplicates, what this function does is compute all sublists that have one less element than the original list and call itself recursively on all of them. So, the number of times `g` is called when starting with a list of size **n** is **g<sub>?</sub>(n) = n · g<sub>?</sub>(n-1) = n!**

Now, let's consider everything else the function has to do. The amount of work at each step of the recursion includes :

- For each element in the original list, constructing a new list of one less element. This is a total amount of work equal to **n<sup>2</sup>**
- Once the result of the recursive call is known, add it to an accumulator. This is a total amount of work equal to **n** (this part can be ignored, since the filter is more costly).

So, since we know how many times each recursive step will be called (based on our previous analysis), the total amount of non-`g` related work is: **t<sub>?</sub>(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + n (n-1)<sup>2</sup> + n (n-1) (n-2)<sup>2</sup> + ... + n!**

This formula looks like a pain, but in fact **t<sub>?</sub>(n) / n!** has a finite non-zero limit as **n** increases (it is the sum of the **k+1  / k!** with **0 < k < n**) and so **t<sub>?</sub>(n) = Θ(n!)**.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  I don't mean to seem mustrustful. This really does look like a functional programming homework because it's not very practical code.

Let F(n) be the number of comparisons plus the number of additions for an input of length n. And let G be the run time of g.  Since g doesn't take any operands, G is constant. We are just counting the number of times its called.

The fold will execute its function n times.  Each execution will call filter to do n comparisons and remove exactly one element from its input each time, then recursively call f on this shortened list and do one addition.  So the total cost is

F(n) = n * (n + F(n - 1) + 1)  [ if n > 0 ]
 = G  [ otherwise ]

The first term expands to

F(n) = n * F(n - 1) + n^2 + n

This is O(n! + n^3 + n^2 + nG) = O(n! + nG) as you proposed.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: the complexity of a function is the number of loops. if you have 2 loops, you have O(n^2). your function is really a bit wild to figure out what is going on inside..

Comment: i think the complexity is O(n^2), because you have List.fold_left and List.filter are 2 loops which is accumulating inside over the loop over functions, isnot it?

Comment: not necessarily 2 loops means `O(n^2)`. it will depend on the nature of the loops, you can make `O(n!)` with a single loop.

Comment: Okay. I'll believe you.  The function won't pass the type checker unless g is a function of zero arguments that returns a number.  Is that what's intended?

Comment: (OCaml doesn't have functions of 0 arguments.  All functions take exactly 1 argument, as in many FP languages.)